# C/C++: socket() creation fails in the loop, too many open files

Tags: c++, c, sockets, select

I am implementing a client-server TCP socket application. `Client` is on an OpenWRT Linux router (C based) and writes some data on the socket repeatedly and in a loop at some frequency rate. The `Server` is on a Linux Ubuntu machine (C/C++ based) and reads data in a loop according to data arrival speed.

**Problem**: Running the `Server` and then `Client`, server keeps reading new data. Both sides work well until the number of data deliveries (# of connections) reaches 1013. After that, the `Client` stuck at `socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)` with `socket creation failed...: Too many open files`. Apparently, the number of open `fd` approaches `ulimit -n = 1024` on client.

I put the snippets of the code which shows the loop structures for `Server.cpp` and `Client.c`:

Server.c:

```c
//    TCP Socket creation stuff over here (work as they should):
//    int sock_ = socket() / bind() / listen()

while (1)
{
        socklen_t sizeOfserv_addr = sizeof(serv_addr_);
        fd_set set;
        struct timeval timeout;
        int connfd_;
        FD_ZERO(&set);
        FD_SET(sock_, &set);
        timeout.tv_sec = 10;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        int rv_ = select(sock_ + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if(rv_ == -1){
            perror("select");
            return 1;
        }
        else if(rv_ == 0){
            printf("Client disconnected.."); /* a timeout occured */
            close (connfd_);
            close (sock_);
        }
        else{
            connfd_ = accept (sock_,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr_,(socklen_t*)&sizeOfserv_addr);
            if (connfd_ >= 0) {
                int ret = read (connfd_, &payload, sizeof(payload));    /* some payload */
                if (ret > 0)
                     printf("Received %d bytes !\n", ret);
                close (connfd_);  /* Keep parent socket open (sock_) */
            }else{
                printf("Server acccept failed..\n");
                close (connfd_);
                close (stcp.sock_);
                return 0;
            }
        }
}
```

Client.cpp:

```cpp
while (payload_exist)               /* assuming payload_exist is true */
{
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
        int sock;
        if (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1)
            perror("socket creation failed...\n");

        int one = 1;
        int idletime = 2;
        setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &one, sizeof(one));
        setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &idletime, sizeof(idletime));
        setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(one));

        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.100.12");
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);  /* some PORT */
        if (connect (sock, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0){
            perror("connect failed...");
            return 1;
        }
        write(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&payload, sizeof(payload));  /* some new payload */
        shutdown(sock,SHUT_WR);

        bool serverOff = false;
        while (!serverOff){
             if(read(sock, &res, sizeof(res)) < 0){
                 serverOff = true;
                 close(sock); 
             }
        }
}
```

**NOTE**: `payload` is `800 bytes` and always gets fully transmitted per one `write` action. Having both codes defined under `int main()`, the client keeps creating sockets and sending data, on the other side, server receives all and would automatically `close()` and leave if client terminates, due to using `select()`. If I don't terminate the `Client`, however, by checking some print logs, it is evident that `Server` successfully receives 1013 payloads before client crashes with `socket creation failed...: Too many open files`.

**Update**:

Following the point mentioned by Steffen Ullrich, it turned out that, the client socket `fd` has no leak, and the existence of a second `fd` in the original loop (which was left open) was making the `ulimit` exceed the limit.

Comment: I am sure `close` _always_ closes the socket on Linux.

Comment: You should be checking the return code when `close()` is called.

Comment: Are you sure it's not closing sock? Is it possible that `close(sock);` *does* close sock but that line of code doesn't actually run? Maybe `connect` failed and because of that, the socket was not closed? The last loop (with `serverOff`) will be an infinite loop if the server shuts down gracefully, because read returns 0 then.

Comment: ^^^^ The above will definitely leak a descriptor. if `connect` fails you blindly return, leaving an open socket descriptor in the wake.

Comment: @user253751  @WhozCraig, it is assumed that server never terminates first, but client. User would terminate the `Client` and this would make `Server` close after timeout. Well, after 1013 messages I never get return for `perror(connect failed)`. It just returns `perror(socket creation failed)`. I think `connect()` works well on client side.

Comment: TIME_WAIT......?

Comment: Your server closes `connfd_` even when it's invalid, when `accept()` returns -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        if(read(sock, &res, sizeof(res)) < 0){
             serverOff = true;
             close(sock);   /********* Not actually closing sock *********/
        }
```

Your check for end of connection is wrong.
`read` returns 0 if the other side has shut down the connection and `<0` only on error.

```
    if (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1)
        perror("socket creation failed...\n");
```

Given the [precedence of operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) in C this basically says:

```
    sock = ( socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1) )
    if (sock) ...
```

Assuming that `socket(...)` will not return an error but a file descriptor (i.e. `>=0`) the comparison will be false and thus this essentially says `sock = 0` while leaking a file descriptor if the fd returned by `socket` was `>0`.

Comment: I already tried `=` and `<` as `read(sock, &res, sizeof(res)) <= 0)`, yet no change in result. When I print the `read`, it shows `-1` . That small `while` loop always gets passed successfully, as otherwise it will stuck in that for ever.

Comment: @zlg: In this case `close` should be called. Are you sure that there are no other file descriptors used somewhere in your code and that these are actually leaking (you don't show the full code, so impossible to tell)? And as said in a comment already, it is definitely leaking if the `connect` fails.

Comment: @zlg: And there are more problems with your code, see updated answer. OR the code you show is not the actual code you use in which case any attempts to find the problem in it are useless.

Comment: That's actually a good point. There is no other socket, but I also handle one log fine throughout the code (which is 1400 lines) and should carefully check all the `fopen` `fclose` matchings on that single file. But, even if that happens, will it necessarily become an issue within the `socket()` creation ?

Comment: @zlg: There is no limit on sockets but on file descriptors in general. Sockets and regular files, pipes, directory handles .. are all file descriptors and subject to this limit. For example with `lsof -p process_id` you can see what file descriptors are currently in use and what they are used for.

Comment: thanks for the update, actually, `sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1` was my typo while transferring the code to this page, that is good on my side. However, I checked the entire code and found one `fopen()` not followed by an `fclose()` on a log `FILE *`. So added the `fclose()` and now I can't see the error for reaching `ulimit`. I also need to return the status for all `fopen()`s as well to avoid misleading errors. Grate point you caught! Thank you